# How to check if the SQL cursor is pointing onto the first record of a file in ile rpg?

Tags: sql, db2, rpgle

I made a file with pictures and its working like a photo gallery.
So, when I go back with F12 I want to see the prior record in the file.

If the cursor is reaching the first record of the file, the program should be closed.

Actually it is going round in a circle, it's loading the prior record and never leaves the loop.

How can tell the program to stop after the first record of a file?

Here's my SQL:

```
     EXEC SQL
     DECLARE C1 SCROLL CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM FILE
     WHERE [variables].....
     ORDER BY ....
     FOR FETCH ONLY;

     EXEC SQL
     OPEN JCBBC1; 

     EXEC SQL
     FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO :FILE; 

     DOW SQLCOD = *ZERO;
       *do something....*
       IF F12 is pressed;
         EXEC SQL
         FETCH PRIOR FROM C1 INTO :FILE;
     ENDDO;
```

Comment: Why would you _close_ the program if you're at the start?  What happens if I want to iterate forward through the collection again?  For that matter, holding a scrollable cursor open is likely a big resource drain - you might be better off batching the records into an in-memory array and iterating through that (which might remove the need for a cursor entirely, if the list of photos is small enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ROW_NUMBER() is a function that generates a psuedo-column containing consecutive numbers starting from 1 and counting up for each row of returned results (hence the name of ROW_NUMBER()).

Comment: That's not really going to help here, because the statement isn't really the problem, it's the rest of the (not shown) code.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code you've shown, SQLCODE should be non-zero and the loop should exit.

Does the actual code have another `EXEC SQL` between the `FETCH` and the `ENDDO`.

If so, that's resetting the `SQLCOD`, you should be checking `SQLCODE` or `SQLSTATE` immediately after each executable SQL statement.